# Spring Data Serialization of Embeddable with ManyToOne References

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, hateoas, spring-hateoas

I have an interesting problem. My data-model is the following:

Type A:

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class A {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
}
```

Type B:

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class B {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
}
```

Embeddable C:

```
@Embeddable
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class C {
  @ManyToOne
  private A a;
  @ManyToOne
  private B b;
}
```

And Type D:

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class D {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @ElementCollection
  @OrderColumn(name = "ORDER_INDEX")
  @CollectionTable(
    name = "d_c_join",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "d_id")
  )
  private List<C> listOfC;
}
```

Deserialization (and storing) the entities works fine. When an object of class D is serialized the following is the outcome:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "ds" : [ {
      "id" : 1,
      "listOfC" : [ { }, { } ],
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8000/ds/1"
        }
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

How can I configure Spring-Data to serialize A and B in C (best would be by their URI).

Comment: i think you just mark the fields on C as eagerload, right?

Comment: no spring-data will look on fields and references of an entity not depending on it is being eager or lazy loaded

Comment: I'm having a similar issue.  Relationships in @Embeddable objects not being serialized. Did you ever manage to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty positive what you're looking for are [Projections](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts). I don't think Spring will serialize referenced collections without it.

See my answer here for more details: [Spring Data-Rest POST to sub-resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33156283/spring-data-rest-post-to-sub-resource/33194602#33194602)